# Jackson - Serialize Java Class with Collection to JSON

Tags: java, json, collections, jackson

I have a Java class called Account. I was hoping to serialize the list of items along with each instance of Account. How do I do this? Also, is it possible to store accounts to one file and then items to a separate file (almost like a database)?

```
public class Account {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Item> items;
    ...
}
```

I have created a custom serializer to write instances of Account class to a JSON file.

```
public class AccountSerializer extends StdSerializer<Account> {

    public AccountSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public AccountSerializer(Class<Account> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Account account, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) {
        try {
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            jgen.writeStringField("id", account.getId());
            jgen.writeStringField("name", account.getName());
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I then write to a file using the following method:

```
public void setAccounts(List<Account> accounts) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule("AccountSerializer");
        simpleModule.addSerializer(Account.class, new AccountSerializer());

        objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);

        try {
            objectMapper.writeValue(new File(fileName), accounts);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you need a custom serializer. What exactly is your problem when just using a vanilla ObjectMapper? Do you have getters for all properties/fields you want to serialize? What is Item? A class? An interface?

Comment: @dnswlt I created a custom serializer because there are other fields within Account that I do not wish to serialize. Item is just a POJO.

Comment: Just add @JsonIgnore to the fields you don't want to serialize